# CSS color attribute ignored

Tags: css

I want the colors of a text box and its link to invert upon hovering over it. But what happens is that first the box's background color inverts, and only when the cursor moves over the text (link) the text color inverts.

```
#nav span:hover { 
  color:white; /* ignored ! */
  background-color:#687078; 
}
```

Apparently the `color:white` is ignored (because a:hover has precedence?)
How can I change both colors simultaneously?

---

full HTML and CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/stevenvh/LvgRJ/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```css
#nav span a { color:#214275; text-decoration:none; }
#nav span:hover { background-color:#687078; }
#nav span:hover a { color:white; }
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LvgRJ/5/)

The problem with your code is that, when you hover `<span>` but not `<a>`, then only `#nav span:hover` rule applies, but not `#nav span a:hover`. You must use `#nav span:hover a` instead.

Off-topic: consider using childhood selectors (`>`) instead of descendant ones, which are a bit slower.

Answer (score 2):

Use the selector:

```
#nav span:hover,
#nav span:hover a {
    color: white;
}
```

Causes the `a` to be coloured when hovering the `span` element; or:

```
#nav span a {
    color: inherit;
}
```

Which causes the `a` to inherit its color from its parent/ancestor.